# How to rearrange attributes of an XML using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xmldom

I have an xml with some attributes and i want to rearrange those attributes.
And i am having different elements with different attributes. I want all elements 'id' as my first attribute.

Here the small example,

```
<item name="product" dep="DE" id="I001">Item</item>
```

and i want to rearrange the attributes like

```
<item id="I001" name="product" dep="DE">Item</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim x As XElement = <item name="product" dep="DE" id="I001">Item</item>

x.ReplaceAttributes(x.Attributes("id").Concat(x.Attributes().Where(Function(a) a.Name <> "id")))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur rply. I am having differnt set of elements not only this element. I have an differnt attributes with differnt elements.I want that id attribute as my first attribute of every element.